# Howto repair a corrupt Sql Server 2005 Data file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a serious problem.
One of our servers crashed. Now I reinstalled the server from scratch and want to restore the sql server 2005 databased.

I chose "Databases -> Attach" to do this, which worked for most of my db files.
However, with one mdf file I get a error message during recover:
The error message is in german, I haven't translated it, but maybe someone knows this error codes or knows a way how to fix it.

### TITEL: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Fehler bei Datenbank anfügen für Server 'Server\Host'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Hilfe erhalten Sie durch Klicken auf: [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.3042.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Datenbank+anfügen+Server&LinkId=20476](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.3042.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Datenbank+anf%C3%BCgen+Server&LinkId=20476)

---

ZUSÄTZLICHE INFORMATIONEN:

Ausnahme beim Ausführen einer Transact-SQL-Anweisung oder eines Transact-SQL-Batches. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Bei einem internen Vorgang wurde eine Inkonsistenz in der 'XYZ'-Datenbank (ID: 14) auf Seite (1:10690) gefunden. Wenden Sie sich an den technischen Support. Referenznummer 4.
Die neue 'XYZ'-Datenbank konnte nicht geöffnet werden. CREATE DATABASE wird abgebrochen. (Microsoft SQL Server, Fehler: 5242)

Hilfe erhalten Sie durch Klicken auf: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5242&LinkId=20476

---

SCHALTFLÄCHEN:

### OK

Comment: I think you're more likely to get an answer if 1) you get the english version of your error and 2) you ask this question over at ServerFault.

Comment: It the page corruption message, restore the database from your uncorrpted archives. You do have backups, right?

Comment: I have a backup from last night that I want to recover. If I try an older file, I loose a whole day of work.

Comment: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/CHECKDB-From-Every-Angle-EMERGENCY-mode-repair-the-very-very-last-resort.aspx

Comment: try translating the error messages...

Comment: Sorry, I was a little in a hurry because of the server crash.
I thought the link and the error codes were sufficient.

Anyway, the verdor of the software that used the db managed to repair it (I don't know how but it works atm).

@ Will: Thx for the hint to ServerFault, didn't know that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pai eu cred ca pagina 10690 din grupul primar este corupta. Daca nu ai de unde sa recuperezi o arhiva trebuie sa incerci sa o repari, desi poti pierde date. Forteaza reparatia cu permitere de pierdere de date.

Comment: P.S. I haven't bother to translate my answer, but is correct.

Comment: The accepted answer is not for this post, but for the link in the comments. Fortunately I don't need to repair the db anymore but thanks anyhow. (Maybe I need it in the future)